# Angular modal is not updating $scope in result

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, modal-dialog

I'm trying to implement a modal window in Angular to prompt a user for an input, I've used almost the same code in a previous app and it worked, I really don't know what is going on here...

Here is the controller that opens the modal (in Coffee Script):

```
.controller('addStreamModal', [
    '$scope', '$modal', '$log', '$http', '$rootScope'
    ($scope, $modal, $log, $http, $rootScope) ->
        $scope.open = ->
            modalInstance = $modal.open(
                templateUrl: "addStream.html"
                controller: 'addStreamModalInstance'
                resolve:
                    public_key: ->
                        "placeholder"
            )
            modalInstance.result.then ((result) ->
                return
            ), ->
                $log.info "Modal dismissed at: " + new Date()
                return
            return
        return
])
```

Now the modal instance controller:

```
.controller('addStreamModalInstance', [
    '$scope', '$modalInstance', '$http', 'public_key'
    ($scope, $modalInstance, $http, public_key) ->
        console.log(public_key)
        $scope.public_key = public_key
        $scope.ok = ->
            console.log($scope.public_key)
            $modalInstance.close $scope
            return
        $scope.cancel = ->
            $modalInstance.dismiss "cancel"
            return
        return
])
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4>Please enter the private key for verification {{public_key}}</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" ng-model="public_key">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

So I click a button and the Modal opens with "placeholder" in the text box, I can also see this test bound to the modal title.  As I endit text in the box, the title continues to update as expected due to binding, however when I click ok, it seems like the $scope.public_key reverts back to "placeholder".  Trying to figure out why.

Comment: Which scope reverts to public_key? addStreamModal or addStreamModalInstance?

Comment: Hum, don't you need to assign the results of the modal callback to your scope variable in the parent controller "addStreamModal"? Never written a single line of cs, but that you are not doing anything with "result" looks weird. Please enlighten me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the value in your `addStreamModalInstance` controller you are working within a different scope than `addStreamModal.`  To update `addStreamModal`'s scope with the value set in `addStreamModalInstance` you can return the selected value (you are doing this by returning $scope) and assign it in the .then invocation of your `addStreamModal` controller.

Your `addStreamModal` would become something like (sorry, my coffeescript is not great):

```
.controller('addStreamModal', [
    '$scope', '$modal', '$log', '$http', '$rootScope'
    ($scope, $modal, $log, $http, $rootScope) ->
        $scope.modalTitle = "placeholder" //defaults this value to placeholder
        $scope.open = ->
            modalInstance = $modal.open(
                templateUrl: "addStream.html"
                controller: 'addStreamModalInstance'
                resolve:
                    public_key: ->
                        $scope.modalTitle
            )
            modalInstance.result.then ((modalScope) ->
                $scope.modalTitle = modalScope.public_key //updates the default value with the value from the modal
                return
            ), ->
                $log.info "Modal dismissed at: " + new Date()
                return
            return
        return
])
```

Comment: Yep this looks less weird :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me.  However I did find a solution which is posted.

Comment: in what way did this not work? the second time you opened the modal window, I would expect that you'd see the text you entered the first time. (e.g. open the modal, edit the key, close the modal, re-open the modal and you should see the value you entered the first time).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have it working now, I went back to the angular example, tested it then slowly adapted it to my needs, heres the code:

```
.controller "addStreamModal", ($scope, $modal, $http, $log) ->
    $scope.public_key = ""
    $scope.open = ->
        modalInstance = $modal.open(
            templateUrl: "addStream.html"
            controller: "addStreamModalInstance"
            resolve:
                public_key: ->
                    $scope.public_key
        )
        modalInstance.result.then ((public_key) ->
            console.log(public_key)
            return
        ), ->
            $log.info "Modal dismissed at: " + new Date()
            return
        return
    return
```

And the instance:

```
.controller "addStreamModalInstance", ($scope, $modalInstance, public_key) ->
    $scope.editable = public_key: public_key
    $scope.ok = ->
        $modalInstance.close $scope.editable.public_key
        return

    $scope.cancel = ->
        $modalInstance.dismiss "cancel"
        return
    return
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text" name="input" class="form-control" ng-model="editable.public_key">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

So I *think* the difference is that I nest the public key into the .editable object in the instance controller.  I don't exactly understand why this works but it does and I'm happy about that.

Comment: The concept and approach are virtually the same as what I posted. Let's try to understand the 'why' so this post can help others.